# WhatsApp Bot Commands didn't work when I execute

Tags: javascript

Sorry for asking again

I was making a commands in My WhatsApp Bots using whatsapp-web.js module, I made it so that Only I can execute the Command

When I test it, it just didn't execute

I already read the documentation and try use `if (chat.isMe) {` and `if (contact.isMe) {` but still no result.

Did I write it wrong?

The Code:

```
client.on('message', async msg => {
    if (msg.body == '.pin') {
        if (contact.isMe) {
            const chat = await msg.getChat();
            await chat.pin();
            msg.reply('This *chat* has been pinned by *Owner*.');
            console.log('[CHAT_PINNED] You were pinned Chat or Group!');
        } else {
            msg.reply('This *Owner!*');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: How is it possible to test the code? I mean do we need to install sth?

Comment: You need to install node.js and then create your folder (name it whatever you want) and install whatsapp-web.js using npm i whatsapp-web.js, after that, make a new file "file.js" and copy my code or example code